# how to add time to C# console array

Tags: c#, arrays, console

I would like to know how to get the filename into an array and load the filename to CSV file. For example, this is the filename, File_1_20170428101607. I want the file name (date and time format – 28/04/2017 10:16:07) to be parse into a column in the output file (csv file). This is the code for time, can you please check and how to add the time to array to be parse to csv file?

```
private static string[] GetFileNames(string path, string filter)
{
    string fileName = @”C:\\Desktop\\File_1_20170428101607.csv”;

    string result;

    result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    Console.WriteLine(“GetFileName(‘{0}’) returns ‘{1}'”,
    fileName, result);

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, filter);
    for (int i = 0; i parsing was not possible -> return null
    {
        return null;
    }
}

     private static DateTime? ParseDateFromFilename(string filename)
    {
        //regex is used to extract the 14 digit timestamp from filename
        var timestamp = Regex.Match(filename, @"\d{14}$");
        if (!timestamp.Success)
        {
            //if no match was found return null
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            //try to parse the date with known timestamp and return
            return DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp.Value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch
        {
            //any error -> parsing was not possible -> return null
            return null;

        }
```

Comment: Do you just need to grab the portion of the filename that contains the date and time and return it as a string, or do you need it as a `DateTime`?

Comment: I need it as a DateTime in csv file, in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

First create a `StringBuilder` that will contain csv content:

```
StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
string filePath = "...";
```

Next create a `for loop` and take values for two columns and append it do `StringBuilder`

```
//for loop start

string fileName = "File_1_20170428101607";
string datePart = fileName.Split('_').Last();
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datePart, "yyyyMMddhhmmss", null);
string dateString = dt.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var firstColVal = fileName;
var secondColVal = dateString;

var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", firstColVal, secondColVal);
csv.AppendLine(newLine);

//loop end
```

After the `for loop` save `StringBuilder` content to your csv file:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv.ToString());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "save StringBuilder content to your csv file:"

Comment: I mean creating new file. I you want to add column to existing file, you can read all text from it, edit adding new column, and then replace file content.